# Applying an error state to a checkbox parent div

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have a standard HTML checkbox to which I want to apply an error state - I understand you cannot apply styling directly to a checkbox so I am trying to apply the styling to its parent div instead.

Consider:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="required">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <input type="text" name="text" class="text-input required">
</div>
```

At the moment I can style the error on the text input using something like:

```
.text-input .error {
    background-color:red;
}
```

But this does not work on checkboxes - I tried using jQuery to get the checkbox parent and to only style the parent on error for a checkbox (i.e. for a textinput just use the above):

```
$("form-row:has(input[type='checkbox'] error)").css("background-color", "red");
```

This does nothing - I don't get any errors but nothing happens to the parent. How can I style the parent div only when the child checkbox has the error class?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know thats because your div wraps around your `<input>` so the background is not visible. Try adding a padding to your div. Or margin to your inputs. As you like.

```
.form-row {
padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: When I view the elements in Dev Tools I cannot see any style being added to the parent div at all - even if it is not visible in the browser then it should still be added to the parent?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed a period before your `error` in the jQuery code. **And** you're missing a period before `form-row` ;). It should be:

```
$(".form-row:has(input[type='checkbox'].error)").css("background-color", "red");
```

Without a period (`input[type='checkbox'] error`) it states that you're looking for in *input of checkbox type **with an error element inside it*** (and as `inputs` are [empty elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element), there is no possibility for anything to be inside them).

Comment: Hi Tomek - I assume you mean a period (.) before error? I tried adding that but it has not made any difference

Comment: Yes, period. Han you confirm (by looking in developer tools) that the input element has in fact an `error` class applied?

Comment: Yes it does - it changes to <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="required error" aria-required="true">

Comment: Ok, I got it - you were missing **two** periods in total ;) I've updated the answer.